# change layout of jframe form designed in netbeans

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, awt, null-layout-manager

I have designed a JFrame using netbeans IDE using absolute layout but when i run my application on other windows systems, the layout changes. Is there a way to provide a consistent layout across different systems?

Comment: I can't see how the layout is being "changed" unless you code for it.  The possibility is there is a difference in font metrics or DPI which is effecting how the layout looks, which is why we encourage the use of layout managers in the first place.  Can you provide any code?

Comment: You really shouldn't be using an absolute layout because different computers have different resolutions. I would suggest using a GridBagLayout. It is quite flexible: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html

Comment: *"Is there a way to provide a consistent layout across different systems?"*  You should not even attempt to do that.  Each GUI should adapt to the system it is on, and the screen-space it is given.

Comment: You should not use the platform look-and-feel, which have components in different sizes per platform. The current NetBeans IDE however picks the Nimbus L&F, and should do more and less.